# How to round corners of an entire app in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want my app to simulate the rounded display corners most modern day smartphones have by rounding the corners of the app and making the background black.
Currently, the [TikTok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOj0X.jpg) app has something like this.

I already tried using the borderRadius property of the [Material](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html!) widget and wrapping the contents into a container with rounded corners. Neither one worked for me.

Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: when you run your app in rounded corner device it automatically set rounded corvner

Comment: Yes, however, I mean to simulate this for devices where the display corners aren't rounded off.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) at the up most level:

Here is a full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Something")),
        body: Container(alignment: Alignment.center, color: Colors.blue, child: Text("hello")));
  }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Maybe you will want to reduce the radius from 20 to something like 8 to have the result similar to the image you provided.